# Symfony form file validation

Tags: php, symfony

I am using FOSUserBundle, but i have overrided the default controllers to create my own logic and forms.

Here is my ProfileFormType.php

```
namespace UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder->add('avatar', 'file', array('required' => false, 'data_class' => null));
    $builder->add('phone', 'text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('gender', 'choice', array(
        'choices'  => array('not specifed' => 'Не указан', 'male' => 'Мужской', 'female' => 'Женский'),
    ));
    $builder->add('birthDate', 'date', array('years' => range(date('Y') -100, date('Y'))));
        $builder->add('locationCountry', 'text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('locationCity', 'text', array('required' => false));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_profile';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_user_profile';
    }
}
```

For this moment, there is no file extension validation. How should i validate extensions? What is the best practice?

I have tried next

```
$builder->add('avatar', 'file', array('required' => false, 'data_class' => null, 'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg'));
```

But it is returning an Error. By the way i want accept only .png and .jpeg files.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to declare specific validation in your Profile Entity?

Comment: the entity is User, i dont save the file exactly in db. I save file name, then just getting that name from db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As as said in my previous comment:

```
/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Only jpeg or png are allowed."
 * )
 */
protected $avatar;
```

Comment: Getting next error. [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Assert\File" in property AppBundle\Entity\User::$avatar was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Comment: A `use` is missing. Add `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;` in User Entity.

Comment: This is the right way to do this, but it is not working right for me, i would like to ask you few questions, can you create chat please?

Comment: just create `Help to Tigran` chat room. I'm waiting for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93286/discussion-between-tigran-muradyan-and-scoolnico).